# ZEIT Now Angular PWA handle 404

Tags: angular, vercel

I have a PWA IONIC/Angular hosted on ZEIT Now. I noticed that sometimes after deployment the app has a blank page when started. After researching I saw that after deploying, browser wants to fetch some cached `.js` files.

Normally, ZEIT Now will just show a 404 or something or raise a http 404 status. But I noticed that the response was the `index.html` (with status 202) which the browser can't handle, because it expects a javascript and not a text/html.

My current `now.json`

```
{
    "version": 2,
    "name": "my-app",
    "routes": [
      {
        "src": "dist/main.*.js",
        "headers": { "Cache-Control": "s-maxage=0, max-age=0" }
      },
      {
        "src": "dist/ngsw.json",
        "headers": { "Cache-Control": "s-maxage=0, max-age=0" }
      }
    ] 
  }
```

How can I handle this?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can try to 404 inexistent hashed `.js` files? Here are a few steps:

1. Use [Advanced Project Settings](https://zeit.co/blog/advanced-project-settings) to get rid of the `dist` prefix.
2. If you want to use `routes` ([reference](https://zeit.co/docs/configuration#project/routes)), after you've fixed the "dist" prefix issue, try:

```
    "routes": [
      { "handle": "filesystem"},
      {
        "src": "/main.*", "status": "404", "dest": "/404"
      }
    ]
```

Comment: hmm never thought of that. I will check it out

Answer (score 0):

Angular is auto-detected and a wildcard route is added so that any route that doesn't match a static asset will serve `/index.html`.

https://zeit.co/docs/v2/build-step#optimized-frameworks

It sounds like the best solution for you would be to disable file hashing so that your js/css assets are not renamed each time.

ZEIT Now already purges the CDN cache so you don't need to worry about stale files.

https://zeit.co/docs/v2/network/caching

Comment: but will this break the service worker detecting a new version of my deployed app?

Comment: You didn’t share the contents of your service worker so I can’t be certain. But the fact that you’re using a service worker makes me think the issue is the caching of the service worker and not the CDN caching.